# Check sum of all primes under two million

Tags: performance, ruby, programming-challenge, primes

I'm exploring ruby by writing a code that [checks the sum of all prime numbers under two million](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10). As I am still in the process of learning ruby, I'm unfamiliar with all the standards and best practices. What I have so far works, but I am certain it can be improved. Where can I improve my code for both readability and speed?

```
def is_prime(n)
    range = n
    i = 2

    while i < range do
        return false if (n % i == 0)
        range = n / i
        i += 1
    end
    true
end

sum = 2
(3..2000000).each do |num|
    if (is_prime(num))
        #puts "#{num}"
        sum += num
    end
end

puts "#{sum}"
```

Comment: As for speed, you should try using athosteles sieve. Also, it's unnecessary to go up to n to decide if it's prime or not, going up to the square root is enough

Comment: Conceptually, primality is an attribute that belongs to an integer. Idiomatic Ruby is pretty hardcore about being object-oriented, so your primality test should be a method of the `Integer` class unless you have a good reason for it not to be. `if num.prime?`, not `if (is_prime(num))`.

Comment: And, as always, notice that except for `2` all primes are odd. So you only need to check 50% of the candidates. Here: `i += 2` with i starting at 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby favours Functional Programming, let me show you an example.

```
def prime?(n)
  limit = Math.sqrt(n).to_i + 1
  (2..limit).all? { |i| n % i != 0 }
end
```

This improves readability as the code makes use of `all?` to implicitly loop (Instead you looped explicitly) and is faster as the limit is the sqrt of n and not n and `all?` short-circuits (returns as soon as one condition is false).

---

Also the second part would benefit from FP:

```
puts (2..2000000).select{ |n| prime?(n) }.inject(:+)
```

In general, in Ruby explicit looping is the exception and not the norm, as there are so many built-ins and shortcuts to make use of.

Each function I made use of here is listed at [The Ruby Enumerable Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) and I warmly suggest studying in detail that page, it will take a bit of time, but the time you will save in the future by using it instead of reinventing the wheel each time will be more than worth it.

Comment: I believe that should be `limit = Math.sqrt(n).to_i` (no +1). Otherwise the sum comes out two off.

Comment: @Shelby115 3 should be 2 in the range

Comment: @FilipBartuzi Cool trick! I knew &: but not :&

Comment: @Caridorc actually I was very wrong. My codesnippet called Fixnum#even? not function defined in main scope